# swift, troubles with generic parameters and constraints

Tags: swift, parametric-polymorphism

I'm writing some tests and mocks for my product but I'm having troubles with generic parameters and constraints...

```
enum ApiResult<Success, Failure> where Failure: Error {
    case success(Success)
    case failure(Failure)
    case disconnected
}

var askedDecodableApiResult: ApiResult<Decodable, Error> = .disconnected

func complete<T>(callback: @escaping (ApiResult<T, Error>) -> Void) where T: Decodable {
    callback(askedDecodableApiResult) //  Cannot convert value of type 'ApiResult<Decodable, Error>' to expected argument type 'ApiResult<T, Error>'
}
```

I'm lost with that error. What should I do to be able to send in my callback the pre-defined answer ? In the end, I want to be able to give my `askedDecodableApiResult` any `ApiResult` sporting a value that either inherits from `Decodable` or inherits from `Error`.

I need your help, thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think that the issue is that your are using `Decodable` as an existential type in `askedDecodableApiResult`. An existential type of a protocol may not conform to the protocol itself, e.g. the `Decodable` existential type does not conform to the `Decodable` protocol while the `complete` function expect it to be `Decodable`. Try to avoid using an existential type in `askedDecodableApiResult`. Use a concrete `Decodable` type instead.

Comment: @LouisLac, your answer was totally correct. But as I couldn't use a concrete Decodable type, and after a long workaround with colleagues, I ended using the trick below : ```askedDecodableApiResult```is now of type Any and I do the cast inside the method. If it can't be casted, it can crash as it is for tests only and it would mean I made a mistake in my test code. Anyway, thank you for your answer :)